# Cant delete text from contenteditable element in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I just ran into this. I have a `<p></p>` element which is contenteditable. I made it to have a maximum character count. It is working in all of the browsers (Chrome, IE10 and above, Opera, Edge) but the FF. The issue is, that after i reach the maximum character count I cant delete any of it in Firefox.

**Here is the HTML:**

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 text-place">
  <p contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return (this.textContent.length >= 500 ? false : true )">
  </p>
</div>
```

Any advice is a appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `event.keyCode != 8` to onkeypress event like this:

```
onkeypress="return ((this.textContent.length >= 50 && event.keyCode != 8 )? false : true )"
```

if you need to use del as well you can add `&& event.keyCode != 46`;

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 text-place">
  <p contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return (this.textContent.length >= 500 && event.keyCode != 8 ? false : true )">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @hsh ! That's what I'm looking for!